# vscode `provideCompletionItem` in Middleware not getting triggered for string

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, embedded-language

I am trying to implement embedded language support for `SQL` in vscode extension using [request forwarding](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages#request-forwarding) mechanism.

According to the documentation we can hijack the completion using `middleware` option and provide the sub-language completion using an existing language server. As an example user can get `CSS` language support inside `HTML` using this mechanism.

In my scenario, I want get `SQL Language` support inside another language (new language) when writing a SQL query.

**Sample Code**

```js
let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
  documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: '.mylang' }],
  middleware: {
    provideCompletionItem: async (document, position, context, token, next) => {
      if (
        !isInsideSQLRegion(
          myLanguageService,
          document.getText(),
          document.offsetAt(position)
        )
      ) {
        return await next(document, position, context, token);
      }

      const originalUri = document.uri.toString();
      virtualDocumentContents.set(
        originalUri,
        getSQLVirtualContent(myLanguageService, document.getText())
      );

      const vdocUriString = `embedded-content://sql/${encodeURIComponent(originalUri)}.sql`;
      const vdocUri = Uri.parse(vdocUriString);
      return await commands.executeCommand<CompletionList>(
        'vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider',
        vdocUri,
        position,
        context.triggerCharacter
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Here the `provideCompletionItem` get triggered each time we write a new character in the editor but it seems that it is not getting triggered when user writes `"` or single quote.

Is there a way to get `provideCompletionItem` when single or double quotes is being entered ?